# How to define level-specific random effects in a 3-level HLM analysis using lmer4 package

Tags: r, lme4

How to define level-specific random effects in a 3-level HLM analysis using lmer package 
I'm trying to estimate a 3-level HLM model (e.g., students nested within classes nested within schools) in which both the intercept (b0) and the slope (b1)  are treated as random at level-2, but only the intercept is treated as random at level-1. 
I tried this code

```
model<-lmer(y~1+x +(1+x|school/class)+(1|school), data=data)
```

which did not work  (it added another random effect called ("school.1"), and the entire estimates seemed strange).   Can anybody help find my mistake?

Comment: My guess is you need `1 + x|school:class` as `school/class` expands to `school` and `school:class`.  If you use explicit naming for classes (i.e., each class has a unique name) you could also just do `1 + x|class`.

Comment: It seems to work! Many thanks!